# ExtJS4, Spring JPA, Restful services, Hibernate application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, extjs4.2

I am working on a book repository application using ExtJS4, Spring JPA, Restful services, Hibernate technologies. I need to create a gridpanel in Extjs which list all the books upon loading the page and there should be a form below the grid which has the ability to add a book. Once the user hits Add button on the form the grid should automatically refresh and show the new book.

Its kind of challenging for me to build everything from scratch. I have built the server side code and getting a response for listBooks and saveBook methods. Now I need to build the ExtJS page that calls my services defined in Spring to show the list of books and add a book. I am struggling with the integration of ExtJS with the server side. I am not able to call the services through extjs. I would really appreciate your help! I am attaching some screenshots. Also I have created Dao and Service classes for their respective Impl classes.

```js
Ext.onReady(function(){

 Ext.create(Ext.window.Window, {
      title   : 'Add Book',
      width   : 350,
      x : 50,
      y : 275,
      layout  : 'fit',
      resizable: false,
      closeAction: 'hide',
      modal   : true,
      config  : {
        recordIndex : 0,
        action : ''
      },
      items   : [{
        xtype : 'form',
        layout: 'anchor',
        bodyStyle: {
          background: 'none',
          padding: '10px',
          border: '0'
        },
        defaults: {
          xtype : 'textfield',
          anchor: '100%'
        },
        items : [{
          name  : 'isbn',
          fieldLabel: 'ISBN'
        },{
          name: 'title',
          fieldLabel: 'Title'
        },{
          name: 'author',
          fieldLabel: 'Author'
        },{
          name: 'genre',
          fieldLabel: 'Genre'
        },{
          name: 'details',
          fieldLabel: 'Details'
        }]
      }],
      buttons: [{
        text: 'Add Book',
        action: 'add'
       /* handler : function(){
         click : this.doAddBook(),
        
         doAddBook: function(){
         
         Ext.window.MessageBox("Hello");
         
         }
        
        }*/
        
      }]
    }).show();
     renderTo: Ext.getBody();
});


Ext.define('BookModel', { 
 extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
 fields : [
 {name: 'isbn', type : 'int'},
 {name: 'title', type : 'string'},
 {name: 'author', type : 'string'},
 {name: 'genre', type : 'string'},
 {name: 'details', type : 'string'}
 ]
});



Ext.define('Bookstore', {
 
 extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
 storeId : 'bookStore',
 model : 'BookModel',
 fields : ['isbn', 'title', 'author','genre', 'details'],
 proxy : { 
  type : 'ajax',
  url : 'http://localhost:2016/SpringRestServiceNew/book/list',
  reader : { 
   type : 'json',
   root : 'books'
  }
 },
 autoLoad : true

});


Ext.define('BooksList', {
 extend : 'Ext.grid.Panel',
 title: 'Books List',
 store : 'Bookstore',
 columns : [
 {header : 'ISBN', dataIndex: 'isbn', flex: 1},
 {header: 'Title', dataIndex: 'title'},
 {header: 'Author', dataIndex: 'author'},
 {header: 'Genre', dataIndex: 'genre'},
 {header: 'Details', dataIndex: 'details'}],
 
 height : 250,
 width : 400,
 renderTo : Ext.getBody()
});
```

```html
<!-- 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Library Application</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="http://cdn.sencha.io/try/extjs/4.1.0/resources/css/ext-all-gray.css" />
<script src="http://cdn.sencha.io/try/extjs/4.1.0/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mycode.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
 -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Library Application</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.0/resources/css/ext-all.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.0/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.0/ext-all.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="mycode.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

[BookController[BookDaoImpl[BookServiceImpl[rest-[web.xml[ProjectStructure][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4bDA.jpg)servlet.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHLd2.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues with your code.

1. Since you want a form to after List, You should create Panel instead of Window.
2. You are rendering the Form Window to the body but not the List

Here is updated code.

```js
Ext.define('BookPanel', {
  extend: 'Ext.Panel',
  xtype: 'bookForm',
  title: 'Add Book',
  resizable: false,
  config: {
    recordIndex: 0,
    action: ''
  },
  items: [{
    xtype: 'form',
    layout: 'anchor',
    bodyStyle: {
      background: 'none',
      padding: '10px',
      border: '0'
    },
    defaults: {
      xtype: 'textfield',
      anchor: '100%'
    },
    items: [{
      name: 'isbn',
      fieldLabel: 'ISBN'
    }, {
      name: 'title',
      fieldLabel: 'Title'
    }, {
      name: 'author',
      fieldLabel: 'Author'
    }, {
      name: 'genre',
      fieldLabel: 'Genre'
    }, {
      name: 'details',
      fieldLabel: 'Details'
    }]
  }],
  buttons: [{
    text: 'Add Book',
    action: 'add'
      /* handler : function(){
          click : this.doAddBook(),
         
          doAddBook: function(){
          
          Ext.window.MessageBox("Hello");
          
          }
         
         }*/
  }]
});

Ext.define('BookModel', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: [{
    name: 'isbn',
    type: 'int'
  }, {
    name: 'title',
    type: 'string'
  }, {
    name: 'author',
    type: 'string'
  }, {
    name: 'genre',
    type: 'string'
  }, {
    name: 'details',
    type: 'string'
  }]
});

var data = {
  books: [{
    isbn: 1,
    title: 'Ed Spencer',
    author: '555 1234'
  }, {
    isbn: 2,
    title: 'Abe Elias',
    author: '666 1234'
  }]
};

Ext.define('BookStore', {

  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
  storeId: 'bookStore',
  model: 'BookModel',
  data: data,
  proxy: {
    type: 'memory',
    reader: {
      type: 'json',
      root: 'books'
    }
  }

});


Ext.define('BookList', {
  extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
  xtype: 'bookList',
  title: 'Books List',
  store: new BookStore(),
  columns: [{
    header: 'ISBN',
    dataIndex: 'isbn',
    flex: 1
  }, {
    header: 'Title',
    dataIndex: 'title'
  }, {
    header: 'Author',
    dataIndex: 'author'
  }, {
    header: 'Genre',
    dataIndex: 'genre'
  }, {
    header: 'Details',
    dataIndex: 'details'
  }],

  height: 250,
  width: 400
});

Ext.application({
  name: 'Fiddle',

  launch: function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
      layout: 'vbox',
      items: [{
        xtype: 'bookList',
        width: '100%',
        flex: 1
      }, {
        xtype: 'bookForm',
        width: 500,
        flex: 1
      }],
      renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Library Application</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.0/resources/css/ext-all.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.0/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```